# How to create a dynamic html wrapper element who doesn't bother the css selectors

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a way to create a certain html wrapper element for `js` purposes only, who doesn't bother the `css`?

So I can still use the `>` sign as selector, like the example.

**Example:**

```css
.container > .row {  
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="divWrapper123">
    <div class="row">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

no, `>` in css always mean direct child. you can instead use jquery to apply styling, or you can give the row another class and use it to style:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="divWrapper123">
    <div class="row m10">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


.container .m10{  
  margin:10px;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, they could apply the ID to the existing parent object `<div class="container" id="divWrapper123">`

Comment: The problem is that I am using a css framework where the `row` needs to be directly after the `container`. The `div` with the `id` will only append when user is logged in to edit something.

Comment: can you add the new class `.m10`? If you can then there is no problem, it will always work